# Ubuntu on Nexus 7 32gb, says only 6gb disk space

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have installed ubuntu on the nexus 7 and have noticed through conky and the file manager that ubuntu says I only have 6gb of disk space. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Are you upgraded to using Raring / **13.04** ?

Answer (score 1):

There is [already a bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1091220). For raring, only "8g" images are being made, which produces a 6g rootfs.  One of the issues with flashing a larger image is that when you flash the Nexus7, it first copies the image to memory and then writes it out. This limits the image size. Android does offer a "sparse copy" which will split the .img files up during the copy operation. However, when we tested this prior to UDS, installs had a 30% failure rate. On promising route might be to resize the image after it copies, when it unpack

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- boot into stock recovery (`volume up + power button`)
- factory reset

or

- lock and unlock the bootloader